# Proof that this set is/isnt convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

Ive got this trigonometric polynomial:

[image]

And with this in mind I need to show that this set is/isn't convex:

[image]

Following this, I need to prove that this function is convex:

[image]

I am completely stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take two elements of the set $\Omega$ and examine the line connecting them $\lambda x + (1-\lambda)x'$. Or try to show that $\Omega$ is an intersection of convex sets or something.

Comment: If the function T(x,w) is convex then Omega is convex because it is the intersection of the points above T and y>0 which is convex but how do you show that the function T is convex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to give a complete answer to the question now that I have figured it out, however, credits to TSF for starting me off with the first part.

a. 
\begin{aligned}
& \forall x, y \in  \Omega \Rightarrow  T(x, w) > 0, T(y, w) > 0 \\\\
& \lambda \in  [0, 1] \\\\
& T(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y, w) \\\\
& = (\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda)y_1) + ... + (\lambda x_n + (1-\lambda)y_n) \cos((n-1)w) \\\\
& = \lambda T(x, w) + (1 - \lambda)T(y, w) \\\\
&  > 0 \text{ -> as shown in the first line} \\\\
& \text{meaning that all points between x and y are in the set and it is therefore convex.}
\end{aligned}

b. 
\begin{aligned}
& \forall x, y \in  \Omega \Rightarrow  T(x, w) > 0, T(y, w) > 0 \\\\
& \lambda \in  [0, 1] \\\\
& - \intop_{0}^{2 \pi} \log T(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y, w) dw \\\\
& = \intop_{0}^{2 \pi} -(\log (T(\lambda x, w) + T(1-\lambda) y, w))) dw \text{ -> we proved this equality in the first part} \\\\
& \leq  \intop_{0}^{2 \pi} -\log T(\lambda x, w) -\log T((1-\lambda) y, w) dw \text{ -> -log is convex since log is concave} \\\\
& =  - \intop_{0}^{2 \pi} \log T(\lambda x, w) dw - \intop_{0}^{2 \pi} \log T((1-\lambda) y, w) dw \\\\
& \text {this means that all points in between are in the set above the function and so the function is convex}
\end{aligned}